# print custom function response in modal popup angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to print my response in my modal popup.

I have a different function for open Modal & my custom function

I want to print my custom function response in modal popup

```
$scope.createUser = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/js/modal-popup.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log) {
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
                };
            },
        });
    }

    $scope.allTest = function() {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'api/url'
                    }).success( function (data) {
                        $scope.data = data.data;
                    }).error(function (response){
                        console.log("error");  
                    });
                }

                <button type="button" name="createUser" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="createUser(); allTest()">Create User </button>

<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Create User</h3>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {{data}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using angularStrap for you modal, in this case you can use the resolve property

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/js/modal-popup.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log) {
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
                };
            },
            resolve: {yourresult: $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'api/url'
                })}
        });
```

Note: the modal only opens if the promise resolves

http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals

Comment: in popup how to call

Comment: What did you mean?

Comment: How to print yourresult response in popup

Comment: read the docs: 

Object containing dependencies that will be injected into the controller's constructor when all the dependencies have resolved. The controller won't load if the promise is rejected.

The only thing you need then is wrting to your scope ...